Does the Telepathic feat allow communication-based spells or features to have their speech requirements bypassed?
In D&D 2014 rules, could having the Telepathic feat allow one to do things such as these:

cast the vicious mockery cantrip silently? Since it only has a vocal component and is basically just insulting someone.
Alternatively, the bard feature Cutting Words requires the target to hear you; could speaking telepathically into its mind bypass that requirement?


No for spells, maybe for other features
Spells
Verbal components are incantations that have to be spoken for the spell to take effect. If Vicious Mockery only required you to convey a message to the target, it would essentially be a componentless spell with a requirement for you to speak and the target to understand you. But it's not; it has a verbal component and must be spoken.
Sage Advice also supports this, saying that the words that must be heard for the spells Suggestion and Command are separate from their verbal components.
Other features
Features like Cutting Words are not necessarily magical like spell components. Hearing is, not surprisingly, not defined in the D&D rules. I see two possible definitions of hearing: sound waves hitting your ears and signals reaching you brain. With telepathy, there are no sound waves that vibrate your eardrums, so that could technically disqualify telepathy as hearing. However, you don't really hear anything until the signal from your ears reach your brain. So one could easily say that telepathy just bypasses the physics and arrive straight at the same end result. That would make telepathic communication equivalent to hearing physically.
I don't see any reason not to allow telepathy for features like Cutting Words and the Mastermind's Master of Tactics.

Is there anything that says that you can't speak at the same time as using telepathy? - therefore potentially meeting the requirement.

@Senmurv I'm not sure I understand what you mean. For spells like suggestion, I would rule that you can do the verbal components of the spell with your mouth and give the actual suggestion telepathically.
